# Python/Flask/Jinja2 not working with Material Design Components for Web

Tags: python, flask, material-design

I have been trying to convert a Python Flask/Flask-Bootstrap/Jinja2 webapp to use Material Design Components for Web, and parts of the application work - I'm trying to make the presentation of the webapp as client side as possible.

I have the latest version of `material-components-web.min.js` and `material-components-web.min.css` loaded into a web page template used to generate all pages served up by Flask.

MDC for Web appears to rely entirely on the use of Node.js, and I am not sure that the .js and .css files that I have found and mentioned in the previous paragraph are simply drop in and use (it's a local webapp, so size isn't an issue), and there aren't any readily compiled .css files for all the subcomponents, only .sass.

Anyway, although some of the styling is correct, dynamic functionality such as floating labels on text fields, validation and so on don't work, and a lot of the positions of the elements are wrong.

I am sure I am missing something small, but what is it?

Comment: Why do you need it based on flask? You could use a front end material bundle and split the views yourself.

Comment: What is "frond end material bundle"? I'm trying to do as much as I can client-side, and have material-components-web.min.js and material-components-web.min.css, which seems to provide some of the styling required. But, for example, text fields with floating labels don't work.

Comment: And I need it based on Flask because I am transferring a python app with a web based user interface from flask-bootstrap to MD. And I don't want to have to rewrite the whole thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that what I was missing in using MDC for web was a data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField" attribute in the div component surrounding my text fields.

This information was available, but not easy to find, on the page https://material.io/components/web/catalog/auto-init/

So for Flask my form generation code in my Jinja HTML template was:

```
{% if field.errors %}
    {% set css_class = 'has_error ' + kwargs.pop('class', '') %}
    <div class="mdc-text-field">
             {{ field(class=css_class, **kwargs) }}
             {{ field.label(class="mdc-text-field__label") }} 
             <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
             <ul class="errors">{% for error in field.errors %}<li>{{ error|e }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="mdc-text-field">    
            {{ field(**kwargs) }}
            {{ field.label(class="mdc-text-field__label") }}
            <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

It should have been:

```
{% if field.errors %}
    {% set css_class = 'has_error ' + kwargs.pop('class', '') %}
    <div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
             {{ field(class=css_class, **kwargs) }}
             {{ field.label(class="mdc-text-field__label") }} 
             <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
             <ul class="errors">{% for error in field.errors %}<li>{{ error|e }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">  
            {{ field(**kwargs) }}
            {{ field.label(class="mdc-text-field__label") }}
            <div class="mdc-text-field__bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

It took me about two days of searching to solve what turned out to be a very simple problem, so I hope I save some of you the same effort.